# Are there applications of martingales other than in finance?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, conditional-expectation, martingales, applications

I’ve only had a brief introduction to martingales and was wondering if there are applications of the theory in other areas of mathematics and in real world applications other than in finance (finance being the obvious one)?

Do they come up at all in differential equations, statistics, physics or biology, for example?

Comment: Martingales are a basic tool in stochastic calculus. In addition to finance stochastic calculus is applied e.g. in electrical engineering, physics, theoretical statistics and biology.

Comment: See e.g. https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Stochastic-Calculus-Applications-2Nd/dp/186094566X.

Comment: [Workshop on Martingales in Finance and Physics](http://indico.ictp.it/event/8947) [ICTP, 2019]: *"In physics, martingales have not been explored much yet. Over the last few years, a new martingale formulation of the non-equilibrium thermodynamics of small systems has been developed within the field of stochastic thermodynamics."*

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Just out of curiosity, isn't stochastic calculus applied in some fields of physics? There even the basics like martingale property of Ito integral and martingale representation theorem involve martingales.

Comment: @fesman Not my field.

Comment: Prior to formal introduction, martingales are latent in many fields. One example is the applications of martingales in survival analysis.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of things can be seem as a martingale, personally, I think it is even annoying that good probability bounds appears from such a simple structure as integrability and the condition
$$ \mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}| \mathcal{F}_n) = X_n. $$

A beautiful application on graph theory/computer science is the diferential equation method for random graphs developed by Wormald, see [this PDF](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3763/1a3c5f843f56bd8d0f9f4e15b4fb31782cec.pdf). In chapter four, for example, the author uses martigale bounds and stopping times to study how many time will it take until a huge connected component appears on a random graph. So, if you believe that graphs, and mainly huge graphs, have applications in other areas and in the real world, we are done.